# Zend Framework 1.9 and Doctrine Integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I'm trying to setup Zend Framework and Doctrine.

There is this previous discussion with ZF 1.8

- [Integrate Doctrine with Zend Framework 1.8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973259/integrate-doctrine-with-zend-framework-1-8-app)

That discussion doesn't take into account the AutoLoader / Bootstrap System.

If I generate an application skeleton with ./zh.sh how would I go about integrating Doctrine.

Answer (score 6):

Found a solution

http://pastie.org/481635
http://pastie.org/481633

Setup autoloader and plugin path in application/configs/application.ini:

```
autoloadernamespaces.0 = "Doctrine"

pluginpaths.ZendX_Doctrine_Application_Resource= "ZendX/Doctrine/Application/Resource"
```

Add paths to models and generated models in public/index.php

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/generated'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Save http://pastie.org/481633 to library/ZendX/Doctrine/Application/Resource/Doctrine.php

Answer (score 5):

Matthew Weier O'Phinney has [blogged](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/220-Autoloading-Doctrine-and-Doctrine-entities-from-Zend-Framework.html) about the issue

Answer (score 3):

I picked up a few pointers from the previously suggested entry by Mathew Weier O'Phinney, as well as entries from Danceric that were originally based on ZF 1.8:

- Doctrine ORM and Zend Framework
  http://www.danceric.net/2009/06/06/doctrine-orm-and-zend-framework/
- Doctrine 1.2 is Zend Framework friendly
  http://www.danceric.net/2009/10/29/doctrine-1-2-is-zend-framework-friendly/

You may also be interested in the following links (a selection of my bookmarks matching "zend framework" and "doctrine"):

- Integrating Zend Framework with Doctrine ORM
  http://roysimkes.net/blog/2009/11/integrating-zend-framework-with-doctrine-orm/
- Integrating Zend Framework and Doctrine
  http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine
- Optimizing Zend Framework and Doctrine applications
  http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/01/17/optimizing-zend-framework-and-doctrine-applications/

Apologies for the plain text links. I am a new user here and subject to strict spam prevention rules.

Answer (score 1):

I built up a ready to use frame for Zend 1.11.11 and Doctrine 2.0.7 development and hosted it under [ZendDoctrineFrame](https://github.com/cbeulke/ZendDoctrineFrame). Feel free to use it!