# Propel or Doctrine for ZF integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine, propel

I have never used any ORM, but the Zend_Db_Table (if you can call it one). I'd like give it a try with some famous ROM and I've only heard of these 2 (Propel and Doctrine).

I tried sometimes in the past but I found it too hard to integrate or maybe I didn't understand how it works.

Now that I'm trying again, I'd like to know which one has easier integration with Zend Framework and which one is easier to work and why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine and Propel are definitely the two best know [PHP ORM's among some others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORM+PHP).

Doctrine has definitely seen some more love from ZF and there is rumors that Doctrine 2 will play a major role in ZF2, though afaik nothing as been confirmed as of this writing.

Here is some links for you to follow:

- [Integrating Propel with the Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/184) (2006)
- [Brandon Savage: The Adventures Of Merging Propel With Zend Framework](http://www.brandonsavage.net/the-adventures-of-merging-propel-with-zend-framework/)

and

- [Ruben Vermeersch: Integrating Zend Framework and Doctrine 1.x](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine)
- [Matthew Weier O'Phinney: Autoloading Doctrine and Doctrine entities from Zend Framework](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/220-Autoloading-Doctrine-and-Doctrine-entities-from-Zend-Framework.html)
- [Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework first date](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/2009/11/doctrine-2-and-zend-framework.html)

Also see these two questions that have additional information and links:

- [Zend Framework 1.9 and Doctrine Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269850/zend-framework-1-9-and-doctrine-integration)
- [Integrate Doctrine with Zend Framework 1.8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973259/integrate-doctrine-with-zend-framework-1-8-app)

Should not be hard to find many more for Doctrine.

**EDIT** very nice one from Phil's comment:

- [Zend Framework / Doctrine integration suite](http://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine)

Comment: Don't know if it's mentioned in any of the linked posts / articles, but you should also check out this Zend Framework / Doctrine integration suite - https://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine

Comment: @Phil very good one. Benjamin Eberlei is actually one of the most active when it comes to integrating Doctrine and ZF and he's contributing to both projects afaik.